# how can I remove the duplicate value next to each other using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list and I want to remove the duplicate value next to each other

```
var idList = new List<int>(){100,100,200,200,300,300,100,100,200,200,300,300}
```

and this is my expected result

```
[100,200,300,100,200,300]
```

how can I achieve this in linq

Comment: Pls show us your code. Especialy how you are trying to ahive  this using efcore.

Comment: How would you do it without linq or efcore? (And how is efcore related in the first place?)

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15125117/4892425) might help you. You can try `idList.Distinct()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Aggregate` in `LINQ` -

```
var idList = new List<int>() { 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300 };
var result = idList.Aggregate(new List<int>(), (current, next) => 
            {
                if (current.Count == 0 || current.Last() != next)
                {
                    current.Add(next);
                }
                return current;
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for some custom distinct logic, The regular `idList.Distinct()` will return in your example `[100,200,300]` which is not what you asked for.

To achieve what you are asking for you can implement an extention method for Linq:

```
public static class LinqExtentions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> CustomDistinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            if (i + 1 < source.Count())
            {
                if (!item.Equals(source.ElementAt(i + 1)))
                    yield return item;
            }
            else
            {
                //we reached the last item
                yield return item;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

And now you can use it like this:

```
var idList = new List<int>() { 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300, 100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300 };
var list = idList.CustomDistinct().ToList();
```